# Approval Process skip by changing status?

Tags: workflow, approval-process

Is that possible to skip the `Approval Process` by changing the status to something like `"void"`
Any pointers?

EDIT:
What I mean is that:

Current situation:

I have a record that user can submit for approval if the user wants the record to approved/reject OR if the user decide not to submit for approval, usually user delete this record.

The solution I want:

if the user wants to discard the record the user should be able to change the status to "VOID" and save the record.

But currently when the user selects the status to "VOID" and safe the approval process throws an error because the status does not match.

I'm looking for a way to escape the approval process when the user changes the status to void and save.

Edit:

Entry Criteria:

[image]

Comment: Status on the record? Can you clarify a bit what you mean here?

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to make sure you have an entry criterion for your Approval Process and not leave it open-ended.

If you have a criteria, make sure you `AND` the existing criteria with `status!=void` that way approval flow only enters when the `status` is other than void.

Check the below screenshot

[image]

Comment: I do have a entry criteria but you saying I can have more than one criteria?

Comment: Yes AND the existing criteria with status!=void that way approval flow only enters when status is other than void

Comment: Ahh got it let me try.

Comment: I created a new record and change the status to `void` and click on `Mark as current status` button then I get the above error

Comment: I updated my question with screen shot.

Comment: Is this from a custom validation rule or a standard error message?

Comment: If this is a custom validation you may need to tweak that to allow for void selection

Comment: but the error message I posted is not coming from custom validation

Comment: What’s the error message in your validation rule?

Comment: `Status can not change without submitting approval.`

Comment: So that’s the error who are receiving?

Comment: i'm not sure who is receiving but thats the only validation to that object i found

Comment: Sorry I meant that’s the error you are receiving! It is the custom validation! Turn off and test it and then you have to modify it to make sure it does not fire when status is void

Comment: any idea how to add the validation to skip `void` ? I tried `NOT(ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status__c),"Void"))` but does not work

Comment: I think it should not be PRIORVALUE and just keep the current value check

Comment: thank you for your help, i got it